# Aspose.OCR fails to read simple JPEG files

Tags: ocr, aspose

I am testing Aspose.OCR, attempting to OCR a simple document, but finding that the OcrEngine.Process() returns jibberish with both my sample document and the sample provided by Aspose.

My code:

```
var license = new License();
license.SetLicense("Aspose.OCR.lic");
OcrEngine ocrEngine = new OcrEngine();
string text = null;
ocrEngine.Image = ImageStream.FromFile("Sample.Aspose.jpg");
if (ocrEngine.Process())
{
    text = ocrEngine.Text.ToString();
}
Assert.IsTrue(text.Contains("TRUTH"), text);
```

The Sample.Aspose.jpg is a copy of [Aspose's GIT sample](https://github.com/aspose-ocr/Aspose.OCR-for-.NET/blob/master/Examples/Data/OCR/sample1.jpg).

The text returned (truncated for brevity) starts with:

> Avi [hhhBuyahLITITI Ll r h u -- - ] ---hhh --III-f LIII-fhh l t} ITI r
>   F8 4 1 T Y L h IiR`lm`'k`pfan order 081Dec
>               -      -
>        hh - hh        -  -   h     - h j : t ITI lblel tljehrerlly }}ollnatffst/t trun IT IT } li III`ckaigf nigh ''I.. } : :;;.et}:
>   fc.'IL:ef:t;;e;atc{1';;;:L IT':c:, ,.,.:,, ., ,...,. ''I

Equivalent jibberish is returned from a [sample GIF](https://github.com/quandis/developer.quandis.net/blob/master/Sample.Disclosure.gif).

Am I missing some simple settings for the OcrEngine?

Comment: Looks like my tests were with images that constitute "boundary conditions" for the Aspose OCR engine. The engine ran fine with "normal" images, but my uses cases tend toward the boundary conditions. Google's Cloud Vision API did a decent job of recognizing the images referenced in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample file that you have used is an example for OMR operation. You may consider the file “**Sample.bmp**” for OCR example. The code snippet is fine. It will work.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Thanks; the sample bmp file worked fine. However, a [sample gif](https://github.com/quandis/developer.quandis.net/blob/master/Sample.Disclosure.gif) taken from a simple PDF returns all jibberish (0 actual English words). Can you suggest what my issue is?

Comment: The image you have shared is compressed and have low DPI. The problem cause could be the resolution of the provided image. 

Please note that the current implementation of the Aspose.OCR APIs perform well with images having resolution of at least 300 DPI and the accuracy rate tends to decrease by decreasing the resolution.